# STOMP subscription issue with ActiveMQ "Classic"

Tags: activemq-classic, subscription, stomp

I have a client service written in Lua. It subscribes to a topic on ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.16.2 via STOMP. The logic of the service is to connect, create a durable subscriptions for all messages on a given topic, and disconnect the connection. The client receives a timeout message when no more messages are available for a topic, which is used as an indicator to send a `DISCONNECT` frame to close the connection. During testing I found that topic message(s) could be in an ack message for `DISCONNECT` command as well surprisingly.

Here are the steps the client takes to subscribe topic messages:

1. Create a TCP connection.
2. Send `SUBSCRIBE` frame to create a durable subscription.
3. Receive all pending topic messages in a loop until no more `MESSAGE` frames are received and a timeout occurs.
4. Send `DISCONNECT` frame (requesting a receipt).
5. Receive any left-over `MESSAGE` frames and eventually a `RECEIPT` frame for the `DISCONNECT`.

The issue is that in Step 5 the client sometimes receives *no frames* and a timeout occurs. However, according to the ActiveMQ logs the `RECEIPT` frame was sent and sometimes `MESSAGE` frames are sent as well. At first, I thought these frames would come when the above steps were run again, but they were never received. They are simply lost.

So what is the best approach to resolve the issue? Is there any configuration in ActiveMQ to change?

Comment: Thanks for replying. 
Yes correct I am using STOMP and ActiveMQ version is version 5.16.2.
"connect (durable)" means a durable connection to subscribe topic messages. Also "transaction loss" meant the lost topic message due to timeout error in the client.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254198/discussion-between-tim-and-justin-bertram).

Comment: Thanks Justin for your comments which are very helpful in solving the issue. I will try a different acknowledgement mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to deal with the potential of lost messages you need to use an acknowledgement mode like `client` or `client-individual`. You're likely using `auto` which means the broker may send (and automatically acknowledge) a message that is never received by the client. This can happen in a lot of different situations (e.g. network failure, client crash, etc.).